# Check if Between Dates and Time Exists in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, ajax

I have this data

```
ID    empID    FromDate    ToDate      FromTime    ToTime
1     00001    09/11/2018  09/11/2018  10:00 AM    11:00 AM
2     00001    09/11/2018  09/11/2018  08:00 AM    09:00 AM
3     00001    09/11/2018  09/11/2018  07:00 AM    08:00 AM
```

Code:

```
SELECT      ID,EmpID
FROM        TableName
WHERE       ((WorkFromDate between @WorkFromDate and @WorkToDate) and (WorkToDate between @WorkFromDate and @WorkToDate))
            AND ((WorkFromTime between @WorkFromTime and @WorkToTime) and (WorkToTime between @WorkFromTime and @WorkToTime))
            AND EmpID = '00001'
```

Ajax :

```
success: function (data) {

                            if (data == '') {
                                // saved;
                            }
                            else {
                                swal({
                                    title: "Warning !",
                                    text: "Already Filed.",
                                    imageUrl: "../assets/plugins/bootstrap-sweetalert/thumbs-up.jpg"
                                });
                            }
                        },
```

Date to insert

```
EmpID = 00001
FromDate = 09/11/2018
ToDate = 09/11/2018
FromTime = 07:30 AM
ToTime = 08:30 AM
```

i want this data to be ignored because this data was already filed between ID 2 and 3.

Thanks

Comment: Try reading that sentence again, and see if you can understand it. It seems, as well, that you forgot to ask a question when you posted your question; it's really important you ask one (otherwise how can we answer you?). What have you tried so far to solve the problem and what were the problems/error you faced? What is the output you're expecting as well?

Comment: Agreed, what you have written is incomprehensible. We don't know what you are saying. Please try editing it so we can understand what your question is. If you have difficulty writing in English then it might be a good idea to ask someone to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is now *"how can i achieve this?"*, but what is **"this"**? Have a look at my comment again. I'm afraid that what your saying this is far from clear; I appreciate there could be a language barrier, so asking for help to translate might be a good idea, as @ADyson suggested. Those expected results will really help with the language barrier though; having a literal answer to what you want to obtain gives us at least a goal, rather than a very loose (guessed) interpretation of what you're trying to say.

Comment: Does that query return the results you want out of interest? The format `{Date} BETWEEN {StartDate} AND {EndDate} AND {Time} BETWEEN {StartTime} AND {EndTime}` isn't the same as `{DateTime} BETWEEN {StartDateTime} AND {EndDateTime}`. Have a look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/61a05/6). Notice the first query returns 2 rows, but the second 4. Which is actually correct?

Comment: @Larnu the second fits perfectly.. thanks for this man.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but if I've understood it correctly, this is what you want.

Convert the input date and times to a `DATETIME`, and do the same for the ones in the table. Then you can use `BETWEEN` to see if the variables fall within the period already in the table

```
SELECT      ID,EmpID
FROM        TableName
WHERE       (CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT(@WorkFromDate, ' ', @WorkFromTime)) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT(WorkFromDate, ' ', WorkFromTime)) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT(WorkToDate, ' ', WorkToTime))
            OR CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT(@WorkToDate, ' ', @WorkToTime)) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT(WorkFromDate, ' ', WorkFromTime)) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT(WorkToDate, ' ', WorkToTime)))
            AND EmpID = '00001'
```

Comment: this is ok, but it will only validate the first result (either desc or asc order)

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Validation only cares about the first result. If it finds one bad result it doesn't matter if there are more or not

Comment: @Mami-Estaño I've updated my code now you've clarified your requirements